# WinForms Show image from Bitmap

Tags: c#, winforms

Is there a way to open/show an image of a bitmap without saving it?
Or maybe is there any junk location where I can save it to and open it from there?

Comment: Where is this Image coming from? A database? From a Web resource? Project's Resources? Clipboard? Other?

Comment: The program created it by himself

Comment: So, did you create a new Bitmap object and you used a derived Graphics to draw something inside it? Can you add the details to your question? It's not very clear what the problem at hand is. Where do you want to show this Bitmap? You have a WinForms app, if has different tools available for this.

Comment: Yes thats the way I did it

Comment: Right. Can't you use a PictureBox or draw it on the surface of a Control? -- The required details are still missing - from the question.

Comment: I dont want to use a picturebox, I want to open it with the windows picture app

Comment: Why is that? The WinForms app you have is perfectly capable of showing a Bitmap without the use of the Shell. Maybe just set the `BackgroundImage` property of new, base Form, and show it. What is the problem in doing this? -- Can you add these details to your question? You just need to [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66851565/edit) it.

Comment: You wanna open the file by windows default photo viewer then delete it when the user close photo viewer window? do you have any privacy manner ? if NOT, My suggestion is to save the image in the windows `temp` folder... it will delete after the next boot up.

Answer (score 1):

```cs
pictureBox.Image = bitmapvalue;
```

thats it :)

Comment: I don't want to show it in a picture box, I wan't to open the image file

Comment: oh, you can save it in temp, but if you want to open the image without saving it, it is better to use picture box (in my opinion)

Comment: Yes, but is there a way without save it?

Comment: I have no space in my program for a picture box

Comment: you can create another form, if there is no space, how will you show the image in the first place?

Comment: I want to open it with the photo app from windows

Answer (score 0):

Go picture box properties. Click Image property > Project resource file > Import > Choose an image > Ok.

[image]

Now you can access the picture like this `Image image = Properties.Resources.Math_Wallpaper;`

Comment: I dont want to use a picture box

Comment: You can import from the background image and select none. After importing you can access the image in the code. Properties.Resources.ImageName.